# Mapbox Geocoding Service with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geocoding, mapbox

I have an angular app that uses the Mapbox Geocoding Service in one component to perform typeahead search and allow user to select a location. In another component I would like to display an OpenLayers map that centers on the selected location.

In the mapping component, I am listening to an rxjs Observable that fires when the Mapbox Geocoding Service `MapiResult` feature is selected. The information within the `MapiResult` feature includes a `bbox` and `center`.

How do I update the OpenLayers view to center on the point returned by Mapbox Geocoding Serivce? The ol/view `centerOn(coordinate, size, position)` parameters are confusing me. I do not know how to go from Mapbox `bbox` and `center` to OpenLayers View `coordinate`, `size`, and `position.

So I have a method in the `MapComponent` that handles updates to the location:

```
onChangeCurrentLocation(location: Location): void {
    this.map?.getView().centerOn(location.center, this.map.getSize() ?? [0,0], [0, 0]);
  }
```

Where `Location` is an interface:

```
export interface Location {
  bbox: [number, number, number, number];
  center: [number, number];
}
```

**Details**:

This service is used to communicate changes between the Mapbox geocoding response and the OpenLayers map.

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class LocationService {
      private _currentLocation: Location | undefined; 
      public get currentLocation(): Location | undefined{
        return this._currentLocation;
      }
      public set currentLocation(value: Location | undefined) {
        this._currentLocation = value;
        this._currentLocationChange.next(value);
      }
    
      private _currentLocationChange: Subject<Location> = new Subject();
      public get currentLocationChange(): Observable<Location> {
          return this._currentLocationChange.asObservable();
      }
      
      constructor() { }
    }
```

This component listens to changes coming from the service and attempts to update the map.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  map: Map | undefined;
  projection: Projection | undefined;
  vectorTile: VectorTile | undefined;
  view: View | undefined;
  zoom = 0;

  constructor(
    private _locationService: LocationService) { }

  private createVectorTile(): VectorTile {
    const vectorTile = new VectorTile({
      attributions:
        '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> ' +
        '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">' +
        'OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
      format: new MVT(),
      tileSize: 256,
      url: `https://{a-d}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6/{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf?access_token=${/*private*/}`
    });
    return vectorTile;
  }

  private initMap(): void {
    this.projection = GetProjection('EPSG:3857');
    this.vectorTile = this.createVectorTile();
    this.view = new View({
      center: this._locationService.currentLocation?.center ?? [0, 0],
      zoom: this.zoom,
      projection: this.projection
    });
    this.map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new VectorTileLayer({
          source: this.vectorTile,
        }),
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: this.view,
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (!this.map) {
      this._zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.initMap());
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(this._locationService.currentLocationChange.subscribe(location => this.onChangeCurrentLocation(location)));
  }

  onChangeCurrentLocation(location: Location): void {
    this.map?.getView().centerOn(location.center, this.map.getSize() ?? [0,0], [0, 0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code? or provide a live link?

Comment: It might be easier to use the `setCenter` or `fit` methods.  In any case you would need to transform the mapbox lat/lon coordinates or bbox to the OpenLayers view projection.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! I'll look into that. I'm sure I can find examples of that in OpenLayers docs.